# XML schema compilation errors - intellisense is not available

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I encountered the following XML validation errors (as translated to English)):

```
The attribute 'http://tempuri.org/S...imSetting.xsd:forms_Id' is ignored because the 'prohibited' value of the attribute 'use' is preventing the inheritance of a'use' attribute of the same name starting from the definition of the base type.
```

When I execute the application that uses this xds, I see the following warning message (translating it to English):

```
"Errors have been produced during the XML schema compilation of the project.  That is the reason that XML intellisense is not available".  Then it indicated the *.xsd file path
```

When I click on the warning message, it generates other 6 more validation errors.  When I locate the source of one of them (in the xds file), it  points me to the following one:

```
<xs:attribute name="forms_Id" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="forms_Id" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="forms_Id" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnforms_Id" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="forms_IdColumn" type="xs:int" msdata:AllowDBNull="false" use="prohibited" />
```

In the xds file, it looks like the following (just the first few likes from a 50+ pages xml file size:

```
"<xs:schema id="MySetting" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/S...MySetting.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/S...MySetting.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/S...MySetting.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" msdata:schemafragmentcount="2">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MySetting" msdata:IsDataSet="true""
```

What are the risk of deploying the software (standalone) to the client with this warnings in mind?

For design of the schema, I used the following relationship:

--
Name: forms_eff
Parent Table: forms
Child Table: eff
Column keys: form_id
External Column Keys: form_id

Relation option:
Relation and constraint of external keys
cascade
cascade
none
Nested Relationship checked

---

Can anyone help where to modify the code/schema design?

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets only for executable code. To format code regularly, simply indent by four spaces or highlight and click the `{}` button.

Comment: It sounds like your XML is not modeled exactly like your classes.  That is, some XML element that your 'forms_Id' element is a child/descendant of has a "use" attribute.  So the parent/ancestor has a "use" attribute and the child has a "use" attribute.  But your classes are modeled such that your child should be inheriting that property from it's parent/ancestor.  If correct, you need to either remodel your XML or your classes so that they are in alignment with each other.

Comment: If I understood, the child doesn't need to use the "use" attribute.  It should instead inherit it from the parent.  For clarity,let me add the relationship information within my question above